# Order collection on single element

Tags: c#, linq

I want to order a list off languages, based on singular items but I'm not quite getting how I could get there. I've made a sample as to easily show the problem:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var langs = new string[] { "DUTCH", "GERMAN", "ENGLISH", "POLISH", "LITHUANIAN" };
        var startupLang = langs[rng.Next(langs.Length)];
        var defaultLang = "ENGLISH";
        
        Shuffle(langs);
        
        //....
        
        foreach(var l in langs)
            Console.WriteLine(l);   
    }
    
    private static Random rng = new Random();  

    public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)  
    {  
        int n = list.Count;  
        while (n > 1) {  
            n--;  
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
            T value = list[k];  
            list[k] = list[n];  
            list[n] = value;  
        }  
    }
}
```

**Output Order:**

- The startup language
- The default language
- Rest of list ordering is not really imported

**Sample:**

Startup: DUTCH, Default: ENGLISH
DUTCH, ENGLISH, GERMAN, POLISH, LITHUANIAN

Edit:
I forgot to mention, the default language and the startup language can be the same. The default language is always at one language, whilst the startup language changes - hence the different assignments.

Also I need an actual list or array sorted in this manner. Cid's approach would work but i'm leaving this open to solutions that a) use linq or/and b) don't create an extra array.

[DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lAqvwP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, why not just `OrderBy` them?

```
var ordered = langs
  .OrderBy(lang => lang == defaultLang ? 1 // default first
                 : lang == startupLang ? 2 // startup second
                 : 3);                     // all the others

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ordered));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "cheat" about the loop that displays the languages, there is no need to involve linq or any restructurations of the array, by displaying first the 2 expected languages, then looping over your array and display everything else, but the default and startup ones :

```
var langs = new string[] { "DUTCH", "GERMAN", "ENGLISH", "POLISH", "LITHUANIAN" };
var startupLang = langs[rng.Next(langs.Length)];
var defaultLang = "ENGLISH";
    
Shuffle(langs);

Console.WriteLine(startupLang);
Console.WriteLine(defaultLang);

foreach(var l in langs)
{
    if (l != startupLang && l != defaultLang)
        Console.WriteLine(l);
}
```

Enumerable version :

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetLanguages(string[] languages, string startupLang, string defaultLang)
{
    yield return startupLang;
    yield return defaultLang;

    foreach(var l in languages)
    {
        if (l != startupLang && l != defaultLang)
            yield return l;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var langs = new string[] { "DUTCH", "GERMAN", "ENGLISH", "POLISH", "LITHUANIAN" };
    var startupLang = langs[rng.Next(langs.Length)];
    var defaultLang = "ENGLISH";
    
    Shuffle(langs);

    foreach(var l in GetLanguages(langs, startupLang, defaultLang))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: The console.writeline was just to make the sample easy to test, i need a list - but your principle would still apply - and its so simple i can only think 'why did i not think of this?'. anyways this is why i still like SO. I'm leaving this question open a bit longer, because i'd also like a linqy approach just to see what that looks like.

Comment: I'm sure you can easily replace `Console.WriteLine()` by `myList.Add()`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create another array or list, you can sort in-place using [`Array.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort) or [`List.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort).

It won't look as elegant as [Dmitry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65249119/1025555) though, because you have to implement a [custom comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1).

A comparison takes two elements and returns:

- `-1` if the left item should precede the right item,
- `1` if the left item should succeed the right item,
- `0` if both left and right have the same sort order

```cs
Array.Sort(langs, (left, right) =>
    left  == startupLang ? -1 : // startupLang precedes everything
    right == startupLang ?  1 : // everything succeeds startupLang
    left  == defaultLang ? -1 : // defaultLang precedes everything, except startupLang
    right == defaultLang ?  1   // everything, except startupLang, succeeds defaultLang
    : 0                         // everything else has the same sort order
);
// langs is now sorted
```

In case `langs` is a `List<string>`:

```cs
langs.Sort((left, right) =>
    // same as above
);
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/67iaBR

Comment: Regardless a great addition to this question, thanks.